# Hibernate : Create Filter on the nested Child of a nested Child

Tags: hibernate, filter

hy,

i got a problem with a type of query a bit complicated. To go straigh this is the SQL query i want to get :

```
select * from Parent parent
left join fetch parent.child child
left joint fetch child.grandchild grandchild with age < 18;
```

The with clause is forbidden because of the fetch.

So i got to use filters. But I didn't find the way to apply the filter on Grandchild I think this is because the @Filter or the @FilterDef aren't in the right class.

For instant I declare the Filter (@FilterDef) in the Grandchild class, and I put the
@Filter(name="age", condition = "age < :age_param) just before the declaration
of the Collection attribute in the Child class.
The classes are like this :

```
public class Parent {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="parent")
    private Collection<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
       private Parent parent;

        @Filter(name="age", condition = "age < :age_param")
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="child")
        private Collection<GrandChild> grandchildren;
    }

@FilterDef(name="majority",
           parameters={@ParamDef(name="age",type="int")}
             )
public class GrandChild {
       private Child child;
       private int age;
    }
```

Then I do :

```
filter = session.enableFiler("majority");
filter.setParameter("age_param",18);

session.createQuery("select * from Parent parent
    left join fetch parent.child child
    left joint fetch child.grandchild")
.list();
```

But there is no condition on the join whith grandchild.

Is there a way to obtain this query ? am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug in the Filter annotation. The filter name is *mayority*, not *age*. And the condition must go in FilterDef annotation as default condition:

```
public class Parent {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="parent")
    private Collection<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
   private Parent parent;

    @Filter(name="mayority")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="child")
    private Collection<GrandChild> grandchildren;
}

@FilterDef(name="mayority",
defaultCondition = "age < :age_param"
parameters={@ParamDef(name="age",type="java.lang.Integer")})
public class GrandChild {
   private Child child;
   private Integer age;
}
```